# Include local files when creating stories for web components?

Tags: web-component, storybook

I have a project I would like to use Storybook with, but I'm not sure it's possible and I can't find any answers to solve the problem I'm having.

The project is a web components project that defines several custom elements using a base component class. For example when you create a new component in the project it looks like this:

```
import { Component } from "..path/to/_component/component.js";

export class Example extends Component {

    // Constructor
    constructor(){ super({
        template: "./example.html"
    }); }

}
```

As you can see an options object with a relative path to a template file is included, which is subsequently loaded by the `Component` class and rendered to the shadow DOM of the web component.

The problem with this is that Storybook seems to live in it's own bubble, so when the component is injected even though the `Component` class comes along for the ride, it doesn't bring `example.html` with it.

Is there any way around this limitation of Storybook?

Comment: How is the external template loaded? Have you considered importing the template and setting it directly to the `template` property?

Answer (score 0):

Use your bundled webcomponents instead of the source.